# How to add a link on a javascript notification

Tags: javascript, notifications, service-worker

I've successfully added JavaScript notifications on my app with the code below, but now I would like to implement a redirection link when clicking on the notification. I've looked at different topics here and tried several things with addEventListener, but none of them has worked yet (I'm a newbie in javascript).
Does anyone have a solution?

```
if(document.querySelector('.notification') != null) {
      Notification.requestPermission()
        .then(permisssion => {
            if (permisssion === 'granted') {
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
            }
        }).then(() => navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js'))
        .then(registration => registration.showNotification(' magasin Alltricks de Bron', {
            body: 'Un client a besoin de vous, si vous êtes disponible, allez sur l interface vendeur pour vous y positionner',
        }));
  };
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the [notificationclick event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/notificationclick_event)

Answer (score 1):

I must be late but for future readers

### Adding link to `showNotification`

The link is added to the data option for the `showNotification` options see more about `showNotification` options [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification)

```
if(document.querySelector('.notification') != null) {
      Notification.requestPermission()
        .then(permisssion => {
            if (permisssion === 'granted') {
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
            }
        }).then(() => navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js'))
        .then(registration => registration.showNotification(' magasin Alltricks de Bron', {
            body: 'Un client a besoin de vous, si vous êtes disponible, allez sur l interface vendeur pour vous y positionner', data: { link_url: "https://yoursite.com"}
        }));
  };
```

listen for click on the notification

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
    console.log("Background new notification:");
    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({ type: "window" }).then((clientList) => {
        console.log("what is client list", clientList);
        for (const client of clientList) {
            if (client.url === "/" && "focus" in client) return client.focus();
        }
        if (clients.openWindow && Boolean(event.notification.data.link_url)) return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.link_url);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("There was an error waitUntil:", err);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can't add links in notifications, you can create a similar experience by letting a user click the notification and then redirecting them to the desired page

```
const redirectURL = "https://www.google.com/"
const yourNotification = new Notification(`Open ${redirectURL} ?`)
yourNotification.onclick = () => { 
     window.open(redirectURL) 
}
```

Make sure you request permissions before trying to show notifications

```js
if (Notification.permission !== "denied" && Notification.permission !== "granted") {
    Notification.requestPermission()
}
```